# How to find location of all cells that contain a search key across multiple sheets, and then get the value of the cell next to it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a excel file with multiple sheets in it.

I am looking for the way to find all cells that contain some string '*s*', and then get the value of the number in the cell to the right of all of these cells.

So lets say the word "cost" appeared in Sheet 1 Cell A5 and Sheet 3 Cell D7, I would want to retrieve the values at Sheet 1 Cell B5 and Sheet 3 Cell E7.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what column this string will appear in on any given sheet? If yes, a `VLOOKUP` may do what you want

Comment: How would you see these values presented? All in one cell? All in seperate cells? It would help if you include some more information about your data, your desired output and your own attempt.